# How to use delegates in Google map API for IOS 6

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, mkmapview, google-maps-sdk-ios

In my iphone app I am using google map SDK for showing nearby restaurants.I am able to show the places.
I have some doubts..

**1. How can I find out the center coordinates of the map ??**

**2. How to revert back to current position ?**

**3.How to find out the map is moved- ie center coordinates changed(just like regionChanged delegate in MKMapView)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should probably be three separate questions, however:

1.

```
GMSMapView* _mapView = ...;
CLLocationCoordinate2D centre = _mapView.camera.target;
```

2.

```
GMSMapView* _mapView = ...;
CLLocationCoordinate2D currentPosition = _mapView.myLocation.coordinate;
CGFloat currentZoom = _mapView.camera.zoom;
GMSCameraPosition* camera = 
    [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget: currentPosition zoom: currentZoom];
_mapView.camera = camera;
```

3.

Use the `[mapView:didChangeCameraPosition:]` delegate method.

Comment: thanks man...

one more doubt...How to set the frame for mapview ?
mapview.frame = CGRectMake(x,y,w,h) is not working...

Comment: If your map view is the root view, then it will be resized to fill the screen. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15596572/google-maps-ios/15598570#15598570

Comment: But this is not working..I add a new view and tried to add the map view in that,but the page is not getting loaded

Comment: Can you post the code you're using - maybe in a separate question?

Comment: Please see this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15675402/how-to-set-the-frame-for-mapview-in-google-gmsmap-for-ios6