# How to set the frame for mapview - in google GMSMap for iOS6

Tags: iphone, ios, google-maps-sdk-ios

I am trying to load places inside Google Map View for iOS6.
How to set the frame for the Map ?
Currently it is fullscreen

```
 -(void)loadView {

   GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:10.00989
                                                        longitude:76.316142
                                                             zoom:15];
   mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
   self.view = mapView_;

   }
```

I tried by creating a new (small) view inside the current view and add map inside that,but at that time the page is not getting loaded.It shows a full black screen

```
 -(void)loadView {

  GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:10.00989
                                                        longitude:76.316142
                                                             zoom:15];
   mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];

   [self.view Addsubview:newView];
   self.newView = mapView_;

  // I also tried like this - [self.newView Addsubview:mapView_;

   }
```

Comment: How did you add newView? Are you using a xib or storyboard, or creating it all with code?

Comment: I am adding it in Xib..not using story board

Comment: any… update from you?

Comment: yes I found the issue...

Comment: @user2115266 What is the solution??? i am facing same issue

Answer (score 5):

You can try... what is working for me :)

```
//header file
...
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet GMSMapView *mapView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *subview; //viewForMap
...
```

implementation file

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:10.8683
                                                            longitude:76.2086 zoom:6
                                                              bearing:0
                                                         viewingAngle:0
                                                                ];
    self.mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:_subview.bounds camera:camera];
  [_subview addSubview:_mapView];
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say if your problem here is adding the map view or something upstream.

Have you set a breakpoint in -viewDidLoad to ensure that it gets called?

Check the bounds of newView to make sure it's what you expect.  Is newView visible?  Is it a subview of self.view ?

One trick you can use when trying to ensure your views are where you expect them is to set the background color to something obvious, like red, and then you can see plainly on screen if it's what you expect.  If you do this and don't see a red box, then your problem isn't with maps, it's somewhere upstream in the code you haven't shown us.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Create a CGRect with the required frame dimensions and set the MapView frame with method `mapWithFrame:` and then add the mapview as main subview.                                 Below is the code which explains all.                                                    `CGRect fr= CGRectMake(0, 44, 768, 960);                                               mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:fr camera:camera];                               mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;                                                    [self.view addSubview:mapView_];`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `loadView` is called when you are using a xib. I haven't tried using the Google Maps SDK for iOS with a xib, as I create all of my views programmatically.

Maybe you could add your map view in `viewDidLoad`? So for example:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:10.00989
                                                    longitude:76.316142
                                                         zoom:15];
    mapView_ = [GMSMapView 
        mapWithFrame: CGRectMake(
            0, 0, 
            self.newView.frame.size.width, self.newView.frame.size.height)               
        camera: camera];

   [self.newView addSubview: mapView_];
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I don't have any experience with using xibs, so I think I'm out of ideas, sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

**You need to do like this**

```
 -(void)loadView {

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:10.00989
                                                        longitude:76.316142
                                                             zoom:15];

    mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:self.newView.bounds camera:camera];

    [self.view addSubview:newView];

    [self.newView addSubview:mapView_];
}
```