# Issue Implementing the Google Maps API Into iOS Application Project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-maps

I may be missing something, but I followed the steps indicated at the [Google Maps SDK for iOS Site](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start#getting_the_google_maps_sdk_for_ios), but so far I have had no success. I tried running the sample code they have at the bottom of the page, and my compiler keeps bugging me with an uncaught exception.

Here is my implementation:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    GMSMapView *mapView_;
}
```

Followed by this in the viewDidLoad:

```
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:-33.86
                                                        longitude:151.20
                                                             zoom:6];
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;
self.view = mapView_;

// Creates a marker in the center of the map.
GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(-33.86, 151.20);
marker.title = @"Sydney";
marker.snippet = @"Australia";
marker.map = mapView_;
```

I did include line:

```
[GMSServices provideAPIKey:@"API Key"];
```

and replaced the API Key string with my actual API Key. Yet I get this at compile time.

[image]

I used a breakpoint, and the exception seems to originate when executing this line:

```
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
```

[image]

Any of your help would very much be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess it wants a minimum frame size. I didn't see anything in the docs, but I would try this...

```
mapView_ = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 200, 200) camera:camera];
```

Or whatever frame size you want with an actual width and hight.

**Edit**

After further review of your code I see

```
self.view = mapView_;
```

It is possible that mapView_ isn't actually a GMSMapView.

**Edit Edit**

After getting the full error log it sounds like it is an import or setup issue.

I would verify that none of the require imports got missed and that the required linker flag -ObjC was added correctly.

Hopefully that helps =)

Comment: Can you scroll up to the top of the exception I see in your log and see why it says it is crashing?

Comment: The reason is:  [GMSMapView animateToCameraPosition:] : unrecognized selector sent to instance (and a hex numbering, I'm guessing, referring to some memory location).

Comment: And sorry for not including it, but mapView_ was instantiated at the beginning of the implementation as a GMSMapView. My bad.

Comment: @DAB Can you add that line to your question plz. It sounds like there may be some issues with how that is declared. That would at lease explain why you are getting the unrecognized selector.

Comment: I also added a screen shot of the log.

Comment: Hmm then looking at the logs it might actually be an import/setup issue. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23170851/google-maps-animatetocameraposition-ios7-issue or look at 6,7,8 of Adding the Google Maps SDK for iOS to your project here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios/start

Comment: You are right! It's the -ObjC rather than the -objC I had on my Other Linker Flag. Make an answer out of it.