# how to get current location in google map sdk in iphone

Tags: iphone, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to set camera on current location and zoom level upto 10.
So I have written code like this and for current location i get hint from this post.

[How to use delegates in Google map API for IOS 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15669308/how-to-use-delegates-in-google-map-api-for-ios-6)

here is my code

```
mapView_=[[GMSMapView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

CLLocationCoordinate2D currentPosition = mapView_.myLocation.coordinate;

 GMSCameraPosition* camera =
[GMSCameraPosition cameraWithTarget: currentPosition zoom: 10];
 mapView_.camera = camera;
 mapView_.delegate=self;

  mapView_.mapType = kGMSTypeSatellite;
  mapView_.myLocationEnabled = YES;

  self.view = mapView_;
  mapView_.settings.myLocationButton = YES;
```

But coordinate is 0.00 in device.

Please Any Can help to solve out this issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [about positioning myself,some problems](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15266118/about-positioning-myself-some-problems)

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet GMSMapView *googleMapView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

- (void)showCurrentLocation {
    _googleMapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {
            GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:newLocation.coordinate.latitude 
                                                                    longitude:newLocation.coordinate.longitude 
                                                                         zoom:17.0];
            [_googleMapView animateToCameraPosition:camera];
        //...
}
```

Comment: Are these delegate methods, where to use this

Comment: `showCurrentLocation` is a custom method of mine that is called when the show location button is tapped in my map view. `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation` is a protocol method of CLLocationManagerDelegate: https://developer.apple.com/library/Mac/DOCUMENTATION/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/CLLocationManagerDelegate/CLLocationManagerDelegate.html

Comment: How to set animateToCameraPosition is default action when click on location button?

Answer (score 3):

You can add an observer for the myLocation property as follows:

```
[self.mapView addObserver:self
      forKeyPath:@"myLocation"
         options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew |
                  NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld)
         context:NULL];
```

You should then implement the following method:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                  ofObject:(id)object
                    change:(NSDictionary *)change
                   context:(void *)context {

    if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"myLocation"]) {

       NSLog(@"My position changed");
    }
}
```

Comment: DO NOT forget to set one of these keys in your Info.plist: `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription or NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`

Answer (score 0):

write this line in info plist

```
CLLocationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization (string) abcd
```

//code and also set annotation pin

.h

```
#import<MapKit/Mapkit.h>

CLLocationManager *locationManager;
@property(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet MKMapView* mapView;
@property(nonatomic,retain)CLLocationManager* locationManager;


- (id)init {
self = [super init];
if(self != nil) {
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.delegate = self;
}
return self;
```

}

in viewDidLoad

```
 _mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
_mapView.mapType = MKMapTypeStandard;
_mapView.delegate = self;


  if(IS_OS_8_OR_LATER) {
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
}

[self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

// NSDictionary *dictlatitude = [_dict objectForKey:@"latitude"];
    float strlatitude = [[_dict objectForKey:@"latitude"] floatValue];

// NSDictionary *dictlongitude = [_dict objectForKey:@"longitude"];
    float strlongitude = [[_dict objectForKey:@"longitude"] floatValue];

```
NSLog(@"Staring Point latitude : %f", strlatitude);
NSLog(@"Staring Point longitude: %f", strlongitude);


MKCoordinateRegion region;
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta = 0.005;
span.longitudeDelta = 0.005;
CLLocationCoordinate2D location;
location.latitude = strlatitude;
location.longitude = strlongitude;
region.span = span;
region.center = location;
[_mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];

MyAnnotation *ann = [[MyAnnotation alloc] init];
ann.title=@"name of the pin";
ann.coordinate = region.center;
[_mapView addAnnotation:ann];
```